# Calculations inside the `for (...)` statement

Tags: c++

A lot of times I see code like:

```
int s = a / x;
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    // do something
```

If inside the for loop, neither `a` nor `x` is modified, can I then simply write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a / x; i++)
    // do something
```

and then assume that the compiler optimizes `a/x`, i.e replaces it with a constant?

Comment: Or check the generated assembly code to be sure.

Comment: If there are possible aliases or if `a` or `x` are global and you call function which may modify `a` or `x`, the optimization is not possible.

Comment: Are `a` and `x` constants?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to store it in a local variable. In certain cases, it can be optimized.

Comment: @remyabel: Not everybody speaks Assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler can be sure that the variables used in the expression in the middle of your for loop will not change between iterations, it can optimize the calculation to be performed once at the beginning of the loop, instead of every iteration.

However, consider that the variables used are global variables, or references to variables external to the function, and in your for loop you call a function. The function could change these variables. If the compiler is able to see enough of the code at that point, it could find out if this is the case to decide whether to optimize. However, compilers are only willing to look so far (otherwise things would take even longer to compile), so in general you cannot assume the optimization is performed.

Answer (score 8):

The most important part of `int s = a / x` is the variable name. It gives your syntax semantics, and lets you remember 12 months later why you were dividing one thing by another. You can't name the expression in the `for` statement, so you lose that self-documenting nature.

```
const auto monthlyAmount = (int)yearlyAmount / numberOfMonths;
for (auto i = 0; i < monthlyAmount; ++i)
    // do something
```

In this way, extracting the variable isn't for a compiler optimization, it's a human maintainability optimization.

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Good point! The answer would be "no, you can't do that because your co-workers will bludgeon you with office supplies."  More seriously, any sane coding standards document will encourage well-named variables for this situation. Willingly and repeatedly violating company documents is good way to get fired.

Comment: You should emphasize that you changed the assignment to a `const` variable.  The OP doesn't use `const` in the example.

Comment: I agree with this and I think it's good that this is pointed out. However I have situations where I simply want to limit the lines of code, and also I'm trying to understand how to write optimized code so that's why I've asked the question. I gave a point for this answer because it provides usefull info, however I did not choose this is as the accepted answer because it doesn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The concern for optimization probably stems from the fact that the condition is evaluated before each iteration. If this is a potentially expensive operation and you don't need to do it over and over again, you can extract it out of the loop:

```
const std::size_t size = s.size(); // just an example
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
}
```

For inexpensive operations this is probably a premature optimization and the compiler might generate the same code. The only way to be sure is to check the generated assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with such Questions is that they cannot be generalized. What optimizations the Compiler will perform and what not can only be determined by a case by case analysis.
I'd certainly expect the compiler to do this if one of the following holds true:

1) Both, A and B are local variables, whose addresses are never taken.

2) The code in the loop is completely inlined.

In practice the last requirement isn't as hard as it looks, because if the functions in the body cannot be inlined, their runtime will likely dwarf the time to re-compute the bound anyway